# Having problems with POST Request while trying to create user - api.php | Laravel PHP Framework

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am having some problems when trying to consume API from api.php file inside a Laravel framework.

I working on one small blog-app project and trying in the same time to make my code more readable and maintainable so I have managed to make `UserController`, inside of it to list all web-based views and show those views to the user. For views especially, I have tried to put them inside a **web.php** and simply added a prefix /user on all routes for the sake of readability.

Here is what I have done :

```
// User Panel - Shows all views generated from UserController::class
Route::prefix('user')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/all',[UserController::class,'showUsersView']); // -- admin only
    Route::get('/create',[UserController::class,'createUserView']);
    Route::get('/edit',[UserController::class,'editUserView']);
    Route::get('/deleted',[UserController::class,'deletedUserView']);
    Route::get('/created',[UserController::class,'createdUserView'])->name('created');
    // Route::post('/createUser',[UserController::class,'create']); -- Notice this las one for later
});
```

Everything works fine, and indeed I am getting all my **views** returned,
but the problem appears with 'api' routes.
All task-related methods I have put in there **(api.php file)** and it is working perfectly for the **GET** request routes.

But, when I try to consume API in the Postman or simply in the browser by sending the **POST** request via form, adding **csrf** token like they say in the documentation no matter that I don't send in this case on the **web-based** route I am getting an **error **.
Here I will provide you also with the code from api.php for user-related group and it's current unfinished routes :

```
Route::prefix('user')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/all',[UserController::class,'allUsers']);
    Route::get('/first/{count}',[UserController::class,'firstNumberUsers']);
    Route::get('/specific/{id}',[UserController::class,'userSpecific']);
    Route::post('/create', [UserController::class,'create']);
});
```

Really don't know what is the problem here, tried to Google it, ask my mentors but nothing ...
Also, in the case that you are asking yourself what is the code for the actually creating the user method, here it is:

```
public function create (CreateUserRequest $request) : RedirectResponse
{

    // API logic for creating a new user
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user->save();
    return redirect()->route('created');
    // return response()->json(['success' => 'User has been created']);
}
```

The validation logic has been replaced to the external request that I have made `CreateUserRequest`.
If you have any suggestions for the approach feel free to suggest me a better one.

When I had replaced the **creation logic** from the api.php to the **web.php** , and inside the form included the **csrf** token I got my method actually working , but still do not know what is the problem with **api.php** and this behaviour .

Comment: You don't need to add `csrf_token` when sending a request in routes registered in `api.php`. Also can you add what error it is produced ?

Comment: @xenooooo  I know , but just in case of the error I have added it . I am not getting error , it leads me to some default Laravel page , not even a 404 Error page . Tried it on using Postman in this case , but on the browser I am only getting an redirection back on the same page .

Comment: If your error is not a 404, then first try a dd of the request to see if you are reaching the function.

If not, check all Middleware associated with your APIs

Comment: Solved . The problem was in the Postman settings , everything works fine but my header in Postman request wasn't set to Accepts : application/json .